# How might I pass text data from the ruby console into my clipboard without saving to a file?

Tags: ruby, unix, clipboard, pbcopy

I'm trying to pass the array contained in a global variable I've created into my clipboard on my mac.

It is very long so I don't want to highlight, copy & paste on my console.

I want to use embedded unix code, specificially the `pbcopy` function for the mac laptop console that allows me to pass text into my computers clipboard, ready to paste.

Were I to do this with a file-save, I'd do something like this (in ruby):

```
stringdata = “kflxkhdoudopudpdpudpudpyddoyod”
File.open("temp.txt"){|f| f.write(stringdata)}
`cat temp.txt | pbcopy`
```

But could I possibly do this without creating a temporary file?

I'm sure this is possible. All things in text are possible. Thanks in advance for the solution

Comment: See this: https://coderwall.com/p/qp2aha/ruby-pbcopy-and-pbpaste

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can just echo it instead if there are no newline characters in the string; otherwise, use the `IO` class.

**Using `echo`:**

```
system "echo #{stringdata} | pbcopy"
```

OR

```
`echo #{stringdata} | pbcopy`
```

Ruby will then just rip the text from memory, inject it into the shell command which opens a pipe between the `echo` and `pbcopy` processes.

**Using the `IO` class:**

If you want to do it the Ruby way, we simply create a pipe with `pbcopy` using the IO class. This creates a shared files between the processes which we write to, and `pbcopy` will read from.

`IO.popen("pbcopy", "w") { |pipe| pipe.puts "Hello world!" }`

Comment: wouldn't I have to put the text in quotations of some kind??

Comment: No, `echo` doesn't require that. Try this code in IRB: `echo #{"helllo this is my test"} | pbcopy` ... You will then be able to paste `hello this is my test` from your clipboard.

Comment: Is this supposed to be able to run in `irb` ? I get this response: `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - pbcopy`
`

Comment: This does not appear to run in `irb`. Here's what happened when I did that.
`$ irb
2.2.2 :001 > echo #{"helllo this is my test"} | pbcopy
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'echo' for main:Object`

Comment: Try using `IO.popen("pbcopy", "w") { |pipe| pipe.puts "Hello world!" }` instead.

Comment: Note that `pbcopy` only exists in OS X. On Linux, you can do something like this: https://coderwall.com/p/oaaqwq/pbcopy-on-ubuntu-linux

Answer (score 17):

Here's a simple one-line method you can paste into your IRB console:

```
def pbcopy(arg); IO.popen('pbcopy', 'w') { |io| io.puts arg }; end
```

Once it's defined you can simply do

```
pbcopy stringdata
```

or copy the result of the last command with

```
pbcopy _
```

Of course, you can also put the method definition in an initializer or something, such as `.irbrc` or `.pryrc` if you use [pry](http://pryrepl.org/). Here's a prettier and slightly more intelligent version:

```
def pbcopy(arg)
  out = arg.is_a?(String) ? arg : arg.inspect
  IO.popen('pbcopy', 'w') { |io| io.puts out }
  puts out
  true
end
```

Comment: This worked for me. Accepted answer did not. "`file name too long`" error. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

You can use [my clipboard gem](https://github.com/janlelis/clipboard/) for a Ruby-API to the system clipboard (which is also platform independet, on macOS it will use the same `pbcopy` utility under the hood), so that you can use it from IRB:

```
require 'clipboard'
Clipboard.copy(stringdata);p
```

Usually, the `copy` method returns the string which was copied. This the reason for the `;p` bit: It is a trick to return `nil` so that the console would not display the actual string data.